# CSS3 support for HTA

Tags: css, hta

Is HTML5 and CSS3 supported by HTA?
If I am planning to use my application only with Windows operating system: It is a simple application that does some basic file handling, is HTA  a viable option?

Will there be any serious performance issues if I use a simple flat file (text file) to store data of my HTA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTAs not only support everything a webpage does—namely HTML, Cascading Style Sheets (CSS), scripting languages, and behaviors—but also HTA–specific functionality. This added functionality provides control over user interface design and access to the client system.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have found some CSS code not supported by HTA, for example border radius on button input (none of this has effect on HTA but does on HTML depending on the browser):
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;

Answer (score 6):

To summarize, you have to include such kind of meta line in your HTA to make it support CSS3:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
```

Comment: But if you do that, you might not be able to use VBScript code.

Answer (score 0):

For me, my VBScript codes ran perfectly even with the active CSS3 support