# CSS animation is not working in HTA

Tags: html, css, animation, transition, hta

I am trying to add some animation to my images in "hta" programme
but css "transition" command doesn't work
this is my style.css file:

```
img {   -ms-transform : translate(20px,20px);
-ms-transition : transform 1s ;}
img:hover { -ms-transform : translate(40px,40px);
-ms-transition : transform 1s ;}
```

I tried `-moz-` `-o-` `-webkit-` ... nothing works, but when I run it as `.html` it works

waiting for your answers and thank you in advance

Comment: If you can provide us with some more information in regards with your markup, or even re-articulate what you're actually trying to do? Your question is hard to understand.

Comment: I am trying to make an image moves when mouse is over , so when I use "transition" in css , it doesn't work in hta programmes but it works when I change it to .html and run it in browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 support for HTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219361/css3-support-for-hta)

Comment: [This ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567887/javascript-version-in-hta/19570684#19570684).

Comment: I think the problem is with IE version .. but thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2):

I tested this HTA on Windows 10, and it works for me !

Just give a try on your side !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test CSS3</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<style>
img {   -ms-transform : translate(20px,20px);
-ms-transition : transform 1s ;}
img:hover { -ms-transform : translate(40px,40px);
-ms-transition : transform 1s ;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<img src="https://i.gyazo.com/843dbef1d43700db12710c283aae4c7c.gif"></img>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes .. it works on windows 10 ... maybe it is a browser problem , I will find out about that .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, transition and animation effects don't work until ie=10

if you use ie=9, they don't work, but if you use ie=11 or ie=edge, vbscript doesn't work

So you have to use ie=10

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=10">
```